# What Dutch government agencies do I inform on my address living abroad, and how?

Tags: bureaucracy, dutch-citizens

I'm a Dutch citizen living abroad.  When I moved, I informed the municipality where I lived that I was leaving to live abroad.  Since then, the only Dutch agency I have ever informed on my whereabouts is the office for remotely taking part in elections.  For all this time, I've been wondering if there are any other agencies I should inform / should have informed.  What Dutch government agencies should I keep informed of my whereabouts when living abroad, if any?  And how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to inform any agency. It could however be beneficial to report any movements outside of the Netherlands to:

- The ministry of foreign affairs for election (you already stated you
  did so)
- The consulate/embassy in your country of resident. Note that this is
  not automatically done if you register for elections. This is specifically interesting to do, if you expect the possible need for evacuations in case of emergencies.
- The pension fund if you have some pension rights
- The social security bank, if you want to apply for so called government retirement (AOW)

Again you don't need to do so and your pension rights are not lost if you don't. Also be aware that you are often on your own, even if you registered.

One think I would advise though is to always have a valid passport. Dutch citizenship law is mirky and in some cases you can loose citizenship if not taken care off. Also be aware of the "pension hole (pensioengat in dutch)". For each year that you don't reside in the Netherlands you loose a certain percentage of your final governmental retirement scheme (AOW).

Comment: Good advice.  Note that foreign elections are administrated by the *municipality* of Den Haag, not by any national department... it's also remarkably informal.

Comment: The possibility of loss of Dutch nationality applies only to dual citizens.  It can be avoided by getting one of three documents every ten years: a passport, an ID card, or a declaration of Dutch nationality. The last costs only €30.  The document must be *issued* less than ten years after the previous document, so do not apply too soon before the ten years elapse.  Also, the ten year period does not apply to minors, so the first such document must be issued before the 28th birthday.  Finally, residence in the EU or in the Kingdom of the Netherlands for 1 year also resets the 10-year period.